# angular 10 :Consider using "forEach" instead of "map" as its return value is not being used here

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube

i get this message error :
Consider using "forEach" instead of "map" as its return value is not
being used here.
declare const require: {
context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
keys(): string[];
(id: string): T;
};
};

```
context.keys().map(context);
```

Comment: The purpose of `.map` is to create an array. You don't seem to be using that array. Thus, that warning message (which i'm guessing is from a lint tool) is pointing out this might not be what you meant to do. I don't know what you're trying to do, so i can't tell you much more.

Comment: map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in some of the comments map() has a return value, which you are not using.

Notice all of the examples here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Are of the form `const a = someArray.map(function)`

Not just `someArray.map(function)`.

That's because a will have a value, as the map() function returns it.